# When the question is about an application & its configuration and in no way related to ubuntu

Tags: discussion, third-party-software

Consider a very realistic situation:

The poster (who runs Ubuntu) asks a question about configuring an application running on Ubuntu. This application has detailed configuration procedures not specific to ubuntu (**but spans all Debian branches**). Also, the poster asks too basic question about working with this application.

To be more clear, this application **does not** ship with default Ubuntu installation.

What is the suggested way to handle such post. Should we immediately direct the poster to *SuperUser* / *StackOverflow* / *ServerFault* whatever applies. Guidance needed.

A few examples:

[Apache sever config](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718100/apache-to-apache-connector-like-mod-jk)

[Apache server basic question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771828/which-port-do-i-need-to-open-so-that-others-can-connect-to-my-www-folder)

[MySQL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744032/pdo-mysql-extension-install)

[php](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337328/php-api-not-matching)

Comment: Do you have examples of such a question?

Comment: Yes,  I will add to question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have looked through the examples you have given, and IMHO they are perfect valid questions, there would be no need to react on them , only to answer them.

De facto all programs you can find in the official repositories and those downloaded from 3rd party are valid as long it it about how to get it running under ubuntu (and its flavors) which is not yet at the end of its support lifetime.

If it's a duplicate question, meaning there is already an answer provided on AskUbuntu flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: I voted to close two of them and downvoted the rest. Those are terrible questions.

Comment: @Braiam The question isn't about if they are good posts, but whether they are on-topic. Also: please don't waste people's time voting to close a question as "unclear" when it has an accepted answer. That's not helpful at all.

Comment: @Seth what's not helpful at all is people wasting people times looking for answers to their problems but not finding them because the post is so vague that makes them think that their problem is the same when is not.

Comment: @Seth oh, and by the way, my votes are for me to use however I like, and I like to use them to impose a higher quality standards for the sites I have "high" reputation, so at least I can brag about that.... right now, I can't.

Comment: @Braiam nobody shall "impose" anything here. Please have a second look at the [Be nice](https://askubuntu.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto the "be nice" was imposed to us by SE, since, hey, this is their house. And also imposed to us that we are free to use our votes since ["voting on questions and answers is the primary mechanism through which the community governs the site on a day to day basis."](http://askubuntu.com/help/why-vote).